# event listener when tab is changed

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I need to store some data every time I move to some other tab in the same window or some other window using chrome storage API or even when a new tab is created. So, basically when my active tab is no longer active anymore.

So, for example, If I am on tab A and then I move to tab B(or create a new tab). When this switching happens from A to B, I need to save data from the website running in tab A. (I am getting the data from the site in tab A using content script.)

A more concrete example would be, suppose I am on YOutube site and I have a timeout timer running(using a content script). So when I move to some other site I want to stop the time get the current remaining time and save that. and if the other site is youtube too(in tab B) I would start the time from the previously saved value.

Is there any event listener for this? I looked at the documentation for `chrome.tabs` but could not figure it out.
I saw `onActivated` event listener but I am not sure if that would be useful.
Or is there some other way to achieve this?

Comment: Use the standard DOM `visibilitychange` event and check document.visibilityState. In the content script.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onActivated) `onActivated`:

> Fires when the active tab in a window changes.

As an alternative, also can use content scripts that notify your extension when a page gain or loses focus with `window.onfocus` and `window.onblur`.
This way you'll be able to track the visibility of the tabs, though you should carefully select the required permission.

Comment: 1) onActivated won't tell which tab was focused previously so you need to describe how to track that info taking in account that the background script may unload meanwhile so the info should be kept in storage. 2) onblur doesn't seem useful as it'll trigger when switching to devtools or to another app.